# How to make this ShaderEffect stop changing the opacity

Tags: wpf, image, directx

I have a control in my WPF application which displays images.  It uses a `ShaderEffect` I wrote from code I found on the web.  Here's the `ShaderEffect` class:

```
public class BrightContrastEffect : ShaderEffect {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BrightnessProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register( "Brightness", typeof( double ), typeof( BrightContrastEffect ), 
                                     new UIPropertyMetadata( 0.0, PixelShaderConstantCallback( 0 ) ) );

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContrastProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register( "Contrast", typeof( double ), typeof( BrightContrastEffect ), 
                                     new UIPropertyMetadata( 0.0, PixelShaderConstantCallback( 1 ) ) );

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty = 
        ShaderEffect.RegisterPixelShaderSamplerProperty( "Input", typeof( BrightContrastEffect ), 0 );

    public float Brightness {
        get { return (float) GetValue( BrightnessProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( BrightnessProperty, value ); }
    }

    public float Contrast {
        get { return (float) GetValue( ContrastProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ContrastProperty, value ); }
    }

    public Brush Input {
        get { return (Brush) GetValue( InputProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( InputProperty, value ); }
    }

    public BrightContrastEffect() {
        PixelShader = m_shader;
        UpdateShaderValue( InputProperty );
        UpdateShaderValue( BrightnessProperty );
        UpdateShaderValue( ContrastProperty );

    }

    private static PixelShader m_shader = new PixelShader() { 
        UriSource = new Uri( @"pack://application:,,,/CustomControls;component/bricon.ps" ) 
    };

}
```

Here's the code for the PixelShader, which is compiled using the DirectX SDK:

```
sampler2D input : register(s0);
float brightness : register(c0);
float contrast : register(c1);

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    float4 color = tex2D(input, uv); 
    float4 result = color;
    result = color + brightness;
    result = result * (1.0 + contrast) / 1.0;

    return result;
}
```

I have a form in my program that displays an `Image` control, which has it's `Effect` property set to an instance of the above class.  There are 4 buttons next to the image, one of which increases the brightness by a fixed step, another which decreases the brightness by the same fixed step, a third which increases the control similarly, and the fourth which decreases the contrast.

My problem is that this code is not just changing the contrast, it's also changing the opacity of the image, so that whatever is behind the image starts to show through it.  And there is something more than a white background behind it.

How do I fix this so it doesn't change the opacity of the image?  I know nothing about the language that the `PixelShader` is written in.

Tony

EDIT:  Here is the XAML for the control that uses this ShaderEffect.

```
<Grid Background="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cs:Channel}}}" 
      MouseLeftButtonDown="MouseLeftButtonDownHandler" 
      MouseLeftButtonUp="MouseLeftButtonUpHandler"
      MouseMove="MouseMoveHandler"
      Name="ChannelGrid">

    <Canvas Name="ChannelCanvas">
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="0"
                   Canvas.Top="0"
                   Fill="Black"
                   Height="{Binding ElementName=ChannelCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}"
                   Name="MapHider"
                   Width="{Binding ElementName=ChannelCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}" />

        <Image Canvas.Left="0" 
               Canvas.Top="0"
               Height="{Binding ElementName=ChannelCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}" 
               Name="CanvasImage" 
               Stretch="Fill" 
               Width="{Binding ElementName=ChannelCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Image.Effect>
                <cs:BrightContrastEffect Brightness="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Brightness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cs:Channel}}}"
                                         Contrast="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Contrast, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cs:Channel}}}" />
            </Image.Effect>
        </Image>
        <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" 
                   Name="LicensePlateRectangle"
                   Stroke="Red" 
                   StrokeThickness="1"
                   Visibility="Hidden" />
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <!-- This canvas is overlaid over the previous canvas and is used to place 
             the rectangle that implements the drag selection box. -->
        <Rectangle Name="ZoomRectangle" 
                   Stroke="White" 
                   StrokeThickness="1" 
                   StrokeDashArray="5 5" 
                   StrokeDashCap="Square" 
                   Visibility="Hidden" />
    </Canvas>
    <ComboBox Background="Transparent"
              BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ComboBoxBorder}"
              FontSize="18" 
              Foreground="{DynamicResource ComboBoxForeground}" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              Margin="0,5,0,0" 
              MinHeight="25" 
              Name="CameraPicker" 
              Panel.ZIndex="1" 
              SelectionChanged="Picker_SelectionChanged"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Visibility="Hidden" />
    <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ControlBorder}"
            BorderThickness="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Margin="0,5,0,0" 
            MinHeight="35" 
            MinWidth="35"
            Name="NameBorder"
            Padding="5,0"
            Panel.ZIndex="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Visibility="Hidden">
        <cs:OutlinedText Fill="White" 
                         FontSize="18" 
                         FontWeight="Bold"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                         MinHeight="25" 
                         MinWidth="25"
                         x:Name="CameraName" 
                         Stroke="Black" 
                         StrokeThickness="1"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                         Visibility="Hidden" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your pixel shader to return alpha = 1 all the time by

modifying this line

```
    return result;
```

to

```
    return float4(result.r, result.g, result.b, 1.0);
```

Not sure of the exact syntax, but you get the idea. :)

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfectly.  And the syntax was right.

Comment: No, that's not working.  I did more testing and the image is still becoming transparent.

Comment: Unless you're modifying the opacity of the control elsewhere, the above change should produce opaque pixels. What other things affect this control's opacity?

Comment: That's it, nothing else affects the opacity.  There's functionality for dragging a rectangle over the image and displaying only the pixels in the rectangle in the control, and another that zooms in or out in incremental steps.  But nothing else affects opacity.  I'll paste the XAML for the user control that uses this into the original question.